# How to add Touch Events [Swipe Left/ Right] to a image gallery

Tags: jquery

I have been working on image gallery [html5] and its working fine in desktop version i would like to add touch based  events for Ipad/Tablet devices.

Can you please suggest how to add touch based events using javascript/jquery.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: Jquery mobile?. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html or this http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/jquery-plugins-that-handle-touch-events-43-items/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This jQuery plugin works well. http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library
Easy to use. Ex:

```
$('.slideshow').touchwipe({
 wipeLeft: function() {$('.slideshow').cycle('next');},
 wipeRight: function() { $('.slideshow').cycle('prev');},
 min_move_x: 60         
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function

swiperight or another direction

```
// jquery mobile
    $("#id").swiperight(function() {
        //do some with $.mobile.changePage function
    });
    $("#id").swipeleft(function() {
        //do some $.mobile.changePage function
    });

// javascript
document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    while(target) {
        if(checkIfElementShouldScroll(target))
            return;
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Iam planning to implement these events either with plain javascript or jquery but not jquery mobile.